# Scroll in ListView in WP7 Silverlight not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, scroll

In the following code:

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex = SelectedIndex;
if (SelectedIndex >= 0)
    listBox1.ScrollIntoView(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

The listbox won't actually scroll.  I've stepped through to make sure SelectedItem is not null, but the list continues to remain at the top despite everything... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider this note [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview%28v=VS.95%29.aspx):

> When the contents of the ItemsSource collection changes, particularly if many items are added to or removed from the collection, you may need to call UpdateLayout prior to calling ScrollIntoView for the specified item to scroll into the viewport.